# Django assertTemplateUsed Fails silently with RequestFactory()

Tags: django, integration-testing

I'm working on a Django 1.7.1 application with a simple app called books.  In creating the integration tests for the various views, I've created tests to check the template and response code for each.  Since some of the views are @login_required, I've separated those into a new test class.  The problem is that the line:

```
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'browse.html')
```

is failing silently.  I've run several variations of the test such as:

```
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'index.html') 
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'brow---se.html')
```

And all of them pass!  Even though those are not accurate templates for this test.

```
# integration_tests.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from ..views import browse

class BookAppUserIntegrationTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='user',
                                         email='user@example.com',
                                         password='password')

    def test_browse_normal(self):
        """
        Tests the browse page for normal user
        """
        request = self.factory.get('/url-is-unimportant')
        request.user = self.user
        response = browse(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'browse.html')


# views.py
@login_required(login_url='error')
def browse(request):
    detail_list = Detail.objects.all()
    context = {'detail_list': detail_list}
    return render(request, 'book_app/browse.html', context)
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `assertTemplateUsed` as a [context manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed) and call `render()` on the response. Try this (note that you don't need the response as the first argument anymore):

```
def test_browse_normal(self):
    """
    Tests the browse page for normal user
    """
    request = self.factory.get('/url-is-unimportant')
    request.user = self.user

    response = browse(request)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    with self.assertTemplateUsed('browse.html'):
        response.render()
```